How can I successfully add event listeners to DOM elements from within a class?
I have a class in an npm package that is meant to act as a timer and latch onto some other elements for the page it is imported to.
class Timer {
    constructor({seconds, buttonSelector}) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
        this.buttonSelector = buttonSelector;

        this._addEventListeners();
    }

    _addEventListeners = () => {
        document.querySelector(this.buttonSelector).addEventListener.bind(this, 'click', function() {
            console.log(this.seconds);
        });
    }
}

But when I instantiate this class, it seems the event listener does not attach to the button, with no console messages shown. I'm able to verify as such because the getEventListeners() function shows nothing and the behavior does not actually happen.
Is there something I'm missing? I suspect maybe I'm not using bind() correctly, but the lack of error messages is confusing me.

Maybe I don't understand classes and bind, but what's the goal behind using bind here rather than just a standard addEventListener()?

Can't see what sense it is supposed to make, that you try to apply bind on addEventListener here. If anything, you'd want to apply it on the function that you are assigning as the handler function - so that in there, you have access the class instance via this - right?

My apologies, oversimplified my source code in this example and forgot to include why I'm needing to call bind. I'm trying to call a property or function of the class within that event listener. Edited to fix this.

No need to call .bind at all, just use
document.querySelector(this.buttonSelector).addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('Test');
});

You only have to use .bind if you want to fix the context in which a function is executed to a specific one. If you want to access the class' instance via this when the handler is running, either use an arrow function:
.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Test', this); // <-- That "this" points to the instance
}); 

or bind the handler function:
.addEventListener('click', (function () {
  console.log('Test', this); // <-- That "this" also points to the instance
}).bind(this));


Thank you, you were right that I was attempting to access the class instance via this (messed up my simplified example in my question). Had a feeling my syntax was off for bind.

Was just able to test and this fixes my problem :)
